# Benford's law - interpret the results of Pearson's Chi-squared test

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, pearson-r

These are the results after applying the R - package [benford.analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/benford.analysis/)

[image]

```
Benford object:

Data: sursa$ca_01 

Number of observations used = 134545 

Number of obs. for second order = 98921 

First digits analysed = 1

Mantissa: 

   Statistic  Value
        Mean  0.513
         Var  0.082
 Ex.Kurtosis -1.172
    Skewness -0.086


The 5 largest deviations: 

  digits absolute.diff
1      1       2798.08
2      4       1501.24
3      5        947.56
4      2        933.20
5      6        472.64

Stats:

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  sursa$ca_01
X-squared = 531.34, df = 8, p-value < 2.2e-16


    Mantissa Arc Test

data:  sursa$ca_01
L2 = 0.0019637, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16

Mean Absolute Deviation: 0.006162794
Distortion Factor: 2.348147

Remember: Real data will never conform perfectly to Benford's Law. You should not focus on p-values!
```

How can I interpret these results? Is Benford's Law satisfied?

If p-value < 2.2e-16 => the null hypothesis is rejected. This means that my data set does not satisfy the Benford's law? The graph of my data is similar with the benford's law graph.

Comment: People are more likely to be able to help if you specify what you think the output tells you and what you do not understand.

Comment: @mdewey If p-value < 2.2e-16 => the null hypothesis is rejected. This means that my data set does not satisfy the Benford's law? The graph of my data is similar with the benford's law graph.

Comment: Please [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts and then edit your question by indenting all computer output by 4 spaces (select a code block and press the code tool - ie. press ${\,}$  at the top of the edit window to do this easily)

Comment: It looks similar but not similar enough. Bear in mind that with a quarter of a million observations almost any null hypothesis is bound to be rejected

Answer (score 1):

The key to interpret your results is in the last line of the print summary:

> Remember: Real data will never conform perfectly to Benford's Law. You
>   should not focus on p-values!

Strictly speaking, if you want to test the ***exact*** null hypothesis that your data follows Benford's Law, you will reject it since your p-value is essentially zero. But as the first plot shows, your data does *not* seem to exhibit any *substantive*, practically meaningful deviations from Benford's Law, regarding the distribution of the first digit (first plot), which is what the result of the Chi-Squared test refers to.

As mdewey has mentioned in the comments, with enough data, even small but not meaningful discrepancies will be statistically significant. As with any statistical model, the point of using Benford's Law is not to literally accept or reject if your data follow the Law exactly: no real data ever will. Benford's law can help you in pointing out suspicious patterns in the data that might need further investigation.

As a side note, testing only the first digit is usually not fine-grained enough to detect meaningful discrepancies. In your specific case, since you have plenty of data, it might be worth looking at the the distribution of the *first two digits*, not only the first digit.

Comment: How do you interpret the sizable over-representation of 1's in the "second order" distribution, then?

Comment: @whuber it could be due to rounding or other artifacts, without the data it is hard to tell. But the Chi-Squared test he is referring to is not the result of the second order test.

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if you could explicitly state you are referring only to the first test, lest readers think (as I did) that you were discussing the entire output.

Comment: @whuber ok I added some other notes in the answer

Comment: The problem is that Chi-square is a bad test for Benford's law.

Comment: @gciriani You misinterpret Morrow's paper.  There are more powerful tests for small samples, *exactly* as there are almost always more powerful tests in any chi-squared application, because the chi-squared distribution is only an approximation to the distribution of the test statistic.

Comment: @whuber not to mention this is completely irrelevant for the question at hand. Regardless of the test, the question is about interpreting the p-value... I can tell you beforehand that almost any real data will not be exactly distributed according to Benford's Law.

Comment: @Carlos Of course! Few real datasets will be exactly distributed according to *any* simply described mathematical law.  But a comment about the applicability of the chi-squared test in response to an assertion that it is "a bad test" in the context of a question that includes the output of a chi-squared test seems perfectly germane and helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Chi square is a bad test for Benford's law. A paper by Morrow (2014) compares several tests, and I would recommend that you read it. From that paper I'm inclined to use the Euclidean distance d*N as proposed by Cho and Gaines (2007).

Morrow, J. (2014). [Benford’s Law, families of distributions and a test basis](https://cep.lse.ac.uk/_new/publications/abstract.asp?index=4486) [Paper]. Centre for Economic Performance, London School of Economics and Political Science.